# How to keep animation running when the home button is pushed - Cocos2d?

Tags: animation, background, cocos2d-iphone, home-button

I have an animation that I would like to keep running when the home button is pushed.

I see the `applicationDidEnterBackground` which has `stopAnimation`.

I've tried commenting it out, but the animation still stops.  Is it possible to keep the animations running after the home button is pushed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If you force updating openGL view then you get crash. Try with GLES sample.